# Why is Node.js waiting to post STDOUT stream data from child_process.spawn?

Tags: node.js, electron, spawn

I just started looking at building apps in `Electron`, so I apologize in advance if I use the construct of words in this question in a way that's out of place.

While learning, I was simply attempting to send all the `STDOUT` data gathered from an IRC bot I created in the past to a `div` element in the application.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bot World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bot World!</h1>
    <button type="button" id="bot_button">Run Bot</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>

<script>
  document.getElementById('bot_button').addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var child = spawn('ruby' , ['/home/syncthetic/Projects/Box/bots/hackthissite']);

    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + String(data));
      document.getElementById('bot_button').innerHTML += String(data) + '</b>';
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + String(data));
      document.getElementById('bot_button').innerHTML += String(data) + '</b>';
    });

    child.on('exit', function(code) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + String(data));
      document.getElementById('bot_button').innerHTML += String(data) + '</b>';
    });

 })
 </script>
 </html>
```

`main.js`

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })

}


app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

The `package.json` is simply calling on the `main.js` file

Source for the IRC Bot: https://github.com/syncthetic/Box/

It appears that no matter what network I connect to, the `Electron` application will wait for a specific amount of bytes before posting to `console.log` and appending to the `output` `div`.

I read that the `exec` command for Node would cause it to read the data into a `buffer`, while `spawn` should allow you to tap into that data in real time.

How can I get this to post to the application in real time, when the program itself is pushing data to `STDOUT`?

For the record, I also tried using `execFile`, and it failed to do what I desire, as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution to my own answer!

Apparently `Ruby`, `Python`, and undoubtedly other applications/languages will send data to `STDOUT` in a buffer by default.

Specifically to fix the issue with the running `Ruby` script, I had to enable `STDOUT syncing` with the following line:

`$stdout.sync = true`